# PHP redirect returning die() information and not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, die

I am trying to redirect a page if the original pay is not accessible.

The check to see if the first page is avalible works as it should. 
This is achived with HttpRequest.

If the page is un-contactable the redirect code is as follows:

```
redirect();

function redirect(){
    header('Location: http://somewebaddress');
    die("SHOULD REDIRECT");
}
```

For some reason the redirect is not completed. 
Runnning this file in the command line reviles that the file returns:

```
"SHOULD REDIRECT"
```

Any ideas as to why it is not redirecting?

Comment: Does the command line even care if you have a redirection in your header?

Comment: Have you echo'd anything prior to the header redirect? Do you have any errors or notices in your error log?

Comment: my guess would be the address is malformed somehow, or the target webpage also has a redirect in it that is bad. what happens if you change the location to something standard, like msn.com?

Comment: The code was run in the command line for debugging purposes, as this function is not run on a 'page'. It is called when the browser loads. Nothing is echo'd above as this would cause a "Cannot modify header information – headers already sent" error. The redirect has been tried with a standard address such as google.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Use `exit;` instead of `die();` and it should work!

Comment: Exit() and Die() perform essentially the same function. It makes no difference in this case which I use.
Also. exit should be called as a function, for instance: exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

Headers aren't necessarily sent immediately. Try replacing the die() with an echo() and see what happens.

Comment: This gives the same response as If I had used die("some string"); The redirect is not completed.